# Chrome extension - how to select all text of tab and copy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, browser, google-chrome-extension

Can anyone tell how to copy entire page similar to pressing Ctrl+A and then copying of current tab to clipboard.

Currently i have this but it is doing nothing though extension is successfully added to chrome:

**manifest file**

```
"permissions":
[
   "clipboardRead",
   "clipboardWrite"
],
// etc
```

**content script**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ text: "text you want to copy" });
```

**background page**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

      var textarea = document.getElementById("tmp-clipboard");

      // now we put the message in the textarea
      textarea.value = msg.text;

      // and copy the text from the textarea
      textarea.select();
      document.execCommand("copy", false, null);


      // finally, cleanup / close the connection
      sendResponse({});
    });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <textarea id="tmp-clipboard"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup**

```
<textarea id="tmp-clipboard"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Copy Page">
```

I cannot get this to work, wonder what I am missing here.

Can anyone please guide on how to mimic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for current tab so that it stores in clipboard ?

Comment: You can use `document.execCommand('SelectAll');` to select entire document, then acces it as `window.getSelection().extentNode.innerHTML`. Also you can read full content from `document.documentElement.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code

- From Chrome 20 sendRequest is [deprecated](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#20) in favor of sendMessage
- From Chrome 20 onRequest.addListener is [deprecated](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#20) in favor of onMessage.addListener
- [Due to CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html#inline_scripts) you can not have  tag in your code

After eliminating these problems your code works as expected.

## Demonstration

Sample demo of your use case

### manifest.json

Ensured manifest has all permissions and registrations

```
{
"name":"Copy Command",
"description":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171654/chrome-extension-how-to-select-all-text-of-tab-and-copy",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"background":{
    "page":"background.html"
},
"permissions":
[
   "clipboardRead",
   "clipboardWrite"
],
"content_scripts":[
{
"matches":["<all_urls>"],
"js":["script.js"]
}
]
}
```

### background.html

Ensured it respects all security changes

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="tmp-clipboard"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

### background.js

Added Listener to Simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    //Set Content
    document.getElementById("tmp-clipboard").value = msg.text;
    //Get Input Element
    document.getElementById("tmp-clipboard").select();

    //Copy Content
    document.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
});
```

### contentscript.js

Passing content to be copied

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ text: "text you want to copy" });
```

## References

- [manifest v2 changes](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html)
- [Chrome 20 Changes](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#20)
- [Background Pages](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/background_pages.html)

Comment: Question: Currently `text you want to copy` get copied to clipboard. How to I modify it so that entire page is copied instead similar to pressing Ctrl A and Ctrl C ?

Comment: @dev02:`chrome.extension.sendMessage({ text: document.documentElement.innerHTML });` will copy the entire html node